# Wordpress. how to get custom fileds in category?

Tags: wordpress

i'm installed Advanced Custom Fields Category on my wp-site. But i couldn't get field in loop categories. Code:

```
$args = array(
    'type'         => 'post',
    'orderby'      => 'name',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'   => 0,
    'taxonomy'     => 'catalog'
);

    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    if( $categories ){
        foreach( $categories as $cat ){
             echo get_term_meta($cat->cat_ID, 'image_cat',true); //empty
        }
    }
```

How i can get fields from ACF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$categories = get_categories( $args );
if( $categories ){
  foreach( $categories as $cat ){
    the_field('image_cat', $cat);
  }
}
```

As normal in ACF first value in function is custom field name and the second one is category object

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = get_categories( $args );
  if( $categories ){
      foreach( $categories as $cat ){
        $taxonomy = $cat->taxonomy;
        $term_id = $cat->term_id;  

        // load thumbnail for this taxonomy term (term object)
        $thumbnail = get_field('image_cat', $cat);

       // load thumbnail for this taxonomy term (term string)
       $thumbnail = get_field('image_cat', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
    }
 }
```